# Ind Category of Finitely Generated k-Algebras

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be the category of finitely generated algebras over a field $k$. Let $\hat{C}$ be the category of functors from $C^{op}$ to $\text{Set}$. Let $k \text{-alg}$ be the category of $k$-algebras. I would like to show

> **Theorem:** $k \text{-alg}$ is the Ind-category of $C$.

I have a functor $F : k \text{-alg} \rightarrow \hat{C}$ sending a $k$-algebra $A$ to the functor $[-, A] : C^{op} \rightarrow \text{set}$ sending a finite $k$-algebra $B$ to the set of $k$-algebra maps $[B, A]$. This is defined on morphisms in the expected way.

I would like to show the theorem by showing that this functor is full, faithful and essentially surjective. Is that the easiest way to go about this?

To see that it is faithful, take $A, B \in \text{Obj}(k \text{-alg})$. If $f, g : A \rightarrow B$ are distinct, then they differ at some $a \in A$. Let $A'$ be the subalgebra of $A$ generated by $a$. Then $[A', f]$ and $[A', g]$ differ, so that $F(f)$ and $F(g)$ differ. This shows that $F$ is faithful.

> **Lemma:** Each algebra in $k \text{-alg}$ is the filtered colimit in $k \text{-alg}$ of its finitely generated $k$-subalgebras.

**Proof:** Let $I$ be the set of finitely generated $k$-subalgebras of $A$. We make $I$ into a category whose maps are inclusions of finitely generated $k$-subalgebras of $A$. Let $F : I \rightarrow k \text{-alg}$ be the functor sending $B \in \text{Obj}(I)$ to $B \in \text{Obj}( k \text{-alg})$, and sending an inclusion of finitely generated $k$-algebras to the same inclusion in $k \text{-alg}$. Let $\eta : F \rightarrow \Delta(B)$ be a cone over $F$, where $\Delta(B) : I \rightarrow k \text{-alg}$ is the constant functor at $B$. For each $a \in A$, let $A_a$ be the algebra generated by $A$ in $a$. Define $f : A \rightarrow B$ by sending $a \in A$ to $\eta_{A_a}(a) \in B$ (we must do this).

How might I show that $F$ is essentially surjective, though?

Comment: This is false. For the correct statement replace f.d. with f.g.

Comment: Oh right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, and your proof will not work because the subalgebra generated by $a \in A$ will not be finite-dimensional in general (e.g. consider $A = k[x]$). The correct proof will end up showing that every $k$-algebra is the filtered colimit of its finitely generated $k$-subalgebras.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I changed my question to suit that after your comment, so people should know that the original question said "finite dimensional" instead of "finitely generated" before. But could you direct me to a correct version of the proof?

Comment: Rough sketch: you want to show that the diagram of all f.g. subalgebras of $A$ has colimit $A$. To do this you examine what a morphism out of this colimit into some other algebra $B$ looks like. It's a compatible collection of morphisms out of each f.g. subalgebra of $A$. This defines uniquely a map $f : A \to B$ where the value of $f(a)$ is determined by any (hence all) of the f.g. subalgebras containing $a$, and this map is a homomorphism because the condition $f(ab) = f(a) f(b)$ can be tested on the f.g. subalgebra generated by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks very much. So this main lemma is pretty much enough to show the rest? I am mostly struggling with the "full on hom-sets part".

Comment: @DeanYoung You actually need finitely *presented* algebras. Algebras are also the filtered colimit of category of all finitely presented algebras mapping to them, and then using the universal property of the colimit and the fact that maps out of a finitely presented algebra commute with filtered colimits, you get the desired result. To see the need, suppose $A\to B$ is the quotient of a finitely presentable algebra by countably many relations; if $A_i$ are the intermediate quotients then $B$ is the colimit of the ind-object $(A_i)$ but the identity on $B$ doesn't factor through any $A_i$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson do you have a reference for Ind categories of compact objects in algebraic categories (or something like that), by chance?

Comment: @DeanYoung This is essentially precisely the theory of finitely locally presentable categories. The canonical reference is Adamek-Rosicky's monograph Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories. They also have a more recent monograph with Vitale on the specifically algebraic case, but I don't think it adds much to this question.